# c# WinForm Direct download doesnt start

Tags: c#

```
    private void Update_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/822512180830273546/823193962961305630/Deimos.exe"), desktop + "Deimos.zip");
    }

    void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToReceive / 100;
        progressBar1.Value = (int)e.BytesReceived / 100;
    }

    void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        metroLabel3.Text = "Download Completed";
    }
```

This just doesnt want to download the file let alone show the progress pls help me !

Comment: More details needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line does not start the task, just returns it:

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/822512180830273546/823193962961305630/Deimos.exe"), desktop + "Deimos.zip");
```

You need to await the async task. Change your void method to async void so you can do this as follows:

```
private async void Update_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
    await client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/822512180830273546/823193962961305630/Deimos.exe"), desktop + "Deimos.zip");
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. [`DownloadFileAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_WebClient_DownloadFileAsync_System_Uri_System_String_) _does not_ return a `Task`, though OP could change to [`DownloadFileTaskAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfiletaskasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_WebClient_DownloadFileTaskAsync_System_Uri_System_String_), which does. I don't think that will resolve the issue, however.